# why my web service is unable to process request after handling 2000 requests successfully?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis

My web service will convert doc, text and pdf files into flash files using print2flash software, but it's working fine for approximately 2000 requests after that it is not proceesing,I'm getting operation time out error message.If I restart the machine the service is working fine for another 2000 requests.
Can anyone help me what could be the reason?and how to resolve this issue?

here is my code where I'm getting the problem.

```
        Print2Flash3.Server2 obj = new Print2Flash3.Server2();
        Print2Flash3.BatchProcessingOptions batchProcess = new      BatchProcessingOptions();
        batchProcess.BeforePrintingTimeout = 60000;
        batchProcess.AfterPrintingTimeout = 10000;
        batchProcess.PrintingTimeout = 120000;
        batchProcess.ActivityTimeout = 30000;
        batchProcess.KillProcessIfTimeout = ThreeStateFlag.TSF_YES;
        batchProcess.ApplyChanges();



        obj.ConvertFile(inputFilename, outputFullPath, null, batchProcess, null);
```

This is my error log information

The User Profile Service has started successfully.

> Windows Management Instrumentation Service started sucessfully
>
> Event code: 3001  Event message: The request has been aborted.  Event
>   time: 10/31/2013 12:15:25 PM  Event time (UTC): 10/31/2013 12:15:25 PM
>   Event ID: c0911a4071c940c580fc3d75d3c36f6e  Event sequence: 2826 
>   Event occurrence: 1  Event detail code: 0    Application information: 
>       Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/code-17-130276759869328000 
>       Trust level: Full 
>       Application Virtual Path: /code
>       Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\code\ 
>       Machine name: server   Process information: 
>       Process ID: 1048 
>       Process name: w3wp.exe 
>       Account name: server\Administrator    Exception information: 
>       Exception type: HttpException 
>       Exception message: Request timed out.
>
> ```
> Request information: 
> Request URL: url
> Request path: path
> User host address: server
> User:  
> Is authenticated: False 
> Authentication Type:  
> Thread account name: server\Administrator    Thread information: 
> Thread ID: 13 
> Thread account name: server\Administrator 
> Is impersonating: False 
> Stack trace:
> ```

this is the error message that I'm getting continuously.

Comment: Show us your code, please.

Comment: There are lots of possibilities.  The two most likely (to me) are **1)** Some of your invocations to `ConvertFile` don't ever end (for some reason) and thus permanently consume a worker thread or **2)** You are running out of memory; though I'd expect a different failure case in that scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several causes to this also [Kirk Woll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189950/kirk-woll) has added some good points.

1.There might be an infinite loop which causes the service to hang
 Ex. exception handling method calls the same method for exception handeling.
Check EventLogs in EventViewer to get  these kind of error if any.

2.Memory leak, may be your application is not releasing the memory after use.
Close any unwanted connection, dispose unused object after your work is done.
Try any memory leak tool

**Suggestion:**
If the above two situation fails then you can automate recycling the application pool for the service.
[image: Change Application Pool recycle settings for automatic recycle after some request]

**EDIT:**

try the following.

```
 obj.ConvertFile(inputFilename, outputFullPath, null, batchProcess, null);
  //not sure if your object has similar methods or not but you can give it a try.
 obj.Close();   
 obj.Dispose();
```

or use the using style.

```
using(Print2Flash3.Server2 obj = new Print2Flash3.Server2())
  {
        Print2Flash3.BatchProcessingOptions 
        batchProcess = new        BatchProcessingOptions();
        batchProcess.BeforePrintingTimeout = 60000;
        batchProcess.AfterPrintingTimeout = 10000;
        batchProcess.PrintingTimeout = 120000;
        batchProcess.ActivityTimeout = 30000;
        batchProcess.KillProcessIfTimeout = ThreeStateFlag.TSF_YES;
        batchProcess.ApplyChanges();

        obj.ConvertFile(inputFilename, outputFullPath, null, batchProcess, null);
  }
```

**EDIT2:**

```
   obj.ConvertFile(inputFilename, outputFullPath, null, batchProcess, null);
   obj = null; //As the object is not disposable, you need to release the memory
               //manually.
```

If *Print2Flash3.Server2* is a custom class then derive it  from IDisposable interface and implement the [Dispose method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface).

```
public class Server2 : IDisposable
  {
   ....
   ....
  public void Dispose()
  {
   this = null;
  }
 }
```

Comment: after recycling also I'm getting the same problem

Comment: Did you get anything in the EventLog ?

Comment: I've added my eventlog in the question.please find log in the question

Comment: When I'm trying to use using statement for my object I'm getting the following error.'Print2Flash3.Server2': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'

Comment: Thanks..print2flash3 is a dll, so I cannot implement Idisposable  and I assined my object to null. after that I restared machine,It takes time to know whether it is working or not.(I'll let you know tomorrow or day after tomorrow).